# grecaptcha.execute() calls data-callback before user challenge

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I want to invoke programmatically the invisible reCaptcha challenge.
 According to [reCaptcha document](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute), I have written the following code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>reCaptcha test</title>
    <script>
        function onReCaptchaSubmit(token) {
            alert("reCaptcha challenge response:\n" + token);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <style>
        .grecaptcha-badge {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="grecaptcha.execute();">Challenge</a>

<div class="g-recaptcha"
     data-sitekey="*******"
     data-callback="onReCaptchaSubmit"
     data-size="invisible">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and `grecaptcha.execute();` is called from an HTML link to display reCaptcha challenge popup. In most cases, It works well. but sometimes, after calling `grecaptcha.execute();` , It  calls back `onReCaptchaSubmit()`, without displaying reCapcha popup and user challenge.


How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may not want to use your real sitekey.

Comment: @colecmc, Thanks, I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

You expect invisible reCaptcha to show user challenge every time you call `grecaptcha.execute()`, but it does not work that way. In my experience, it shows challenge only when it has doubts about you. If Google is sure that you are human, it skips displaying of user challenge and proceeds to callback.

Comment: That is also my experience - the hidden captcha does only challange you, if it thinks you're a bot.

Answer (score 2):

Since recaptcha has an expiration time, you have to wait until your recaptcha session expires or call `grecaptcha.reset()` inside `onRecaptchaSubmit` to ensure user challenge appear everytime user clicks the link:

```
function onRecaptchaSubmit(token) {
  /* any behavior you want */
  //...
  window.grecaptcha.reset();
}
```

Comment: I did your workaround, and it seemed that the issue was fixed, but after several tests, I realised that the problem was not solved. Do you think , it is a  reCaptcha behavior or something else?